# Error: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape' when using .corr

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns from a dataframe that I want to get the Correlation Coefficient for:
df['a'] and df['b'] there are around 15 or 20 rows of data.

I assign these to "col1" and "col2" and try and call the corr method:

```
    col1 = df['a']
    col2 = df['b']
    corr = col1.corr(col2,method="pearson")
```

I get an error: 'float' object has no attribute 'shape'

If I import the stats library and try:

```
 corr, pval=stats.pearsonr(col1,col2)
```

I get a correlation coefficient. So what did I do wrong on the first one?

In answer to one of the comments, I checked the type of col1 and col2 and they are both series. I thought this would work since I went to this link in the documentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html
Which gives no indication that you need to specify this is a series rather than a dataframe.

I also checked the type of the full dataframe:

```
print(type(df))
```

And it comes back as type dataframe
The full dataframe is 21 columns with an index. I only want to get the Correlation Coefficient for two of the columns.
Here is a subset of the data I get if I print col1 and col2:
col1:
Country
Indonesia              9.3659e-05
Japan                  0.000388417
Canada                 0.001638514
...
Name: a, dtype: object

col2:
Country
Indonesia             65
Japan                 194
Canada                167
...
Name: b, dtype: object

Is the index of Country causing the problem?

Comment: can you `print(col1, col2)`

Comment: Are you sure `df` is a DataFrame and not a Series? This would explain the error

Comment: share your dataframe data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either, `df` is a Series:

```
>>> df
a    10.0
b    12.0
dtype: float64
```

or a columns of your dataframe has a wrong type:

```
>>> df
      a     b
0  10.0  20.0
1  12.0  22.0

>>> df.dtypes
a    float64
b     object
dtype: object
```